# awscli - lambda function update trigger

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, gitlab

We have a lambda@edge function which listens to cloudfront distribution origin `request` and `response` events. We are trying to automate the deployment. So far we succeeding in updating the code and publishing the new version.

```
  - npm install
  - zip -r lambda.zip *
  - aws lambda update-function-code --function-name LambdaFunction1 --zip-file fileb://lambda.zip
  - aws lambda publish-version --function-name LambdaFunction1
```

But how do we update CloudFront triggers to point to the latest published version?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I cannot find any information about publishing a new lambda version to CloudFront.

Answer (score 4):

Perform the following steps-

1. Check the versions of lambda first by running the following cli
   command. And the Fetch the FunctionARN of the latest version.

> `aws lambda list-versions-by-function --function-name LAMBDA_NAME`

2. Get the cloudfront distribution json data first by the following command.

> `aws cloudfront get-distribution-config --id DISTRIBUTION_ID > cf_config.json`

3. Create a file named `updated_cf_config.json` by fetching **DistributionConfig** key from the cf_config.json.
4. Now Put the FunctionARN of the latest Version of lambda inside the
   "LambdaFunctionAssociations" -> "LambdaFunctionARN"
5. Update cloudfront distribution by running the command. To update the cloudfront distribution we need ETAG from `cf_config.json`:

> `aws cloudfront update-distribution --distribution-config file://cf_config.json --id DISTRIBUTION_ID --if-match ETAG`

Answer (score 0):

Should anyone stumble upon this, I created a simple Node.js script to handle the CloudFront update.

It requires you capture the response of the `aws lambda publish-version` command into `lambda_publish_response.json`, and that you change the `cloudFrontDistributionId` variable, but everything else "should just work":

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const {exec} = require('child_process');

const cloudFrontDistributionId = 'EXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
const currentCloudFrontConfigFile = 'cf_config.json';
const updatedCloudFrontConfigFile = 'cf_config_updated.json';
const lambdaPublishResponseFile = 'lambda_publish_response.json';

exec(`aws cloudfront get-distribution-config --id ${cloudFrontDistributionId} > ${currentCloudFrontConfigFile}`, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (error) {
        console.error(`error: ${error.message}`);

        return process.exit(1);
    }

    if (stderr) {
        console.error(`stderr: ${stderr}`);

        return process.exit(1);
    }

    if (!fs.existsSync(lambdaPublishResponseFile)) {
        console.error('Run this first: `aws lambda publish-version --function-name LambdaFunctionName > lambda_publish_response.json`');

        return process.exit(1);
    }

    let cfConfig = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(currentCloudFrontConfigFile));
    const etag = cfConfig.ETag;
    const lambdaPublishData = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(lambdaPublishResponseFile));

    cfConfig.DistributionConfig.DefaultCacheBehavior.LambdaFunctionAssociations.Items[0].LambdaFunctionARN = lambdaPublishData.FunctionArn;

    fs.writeFileSync(updatedCloudFrontConfigFile, JSON.stringify(cfConfig.DistributionConfig));

    exec(`aws cloudfront update-distribution --distribution-config file://${updatedCloudFrontConfigFile} --id ${cloudFrontDistributionId} --if-match ${etag}`, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
        if (error) {
            return console.error(`error: ${error.message}`);
        }

        if (stderr) {
            return console.error(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
        }

        console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);

        fs.unlinkSync(lambdaPublishResponseFile);
        fs.unlinkSync(currentCloudFrontConfigFile);
        fs.unlinkSync(updatedCloudFrontConfigFile);
    });
});
```

Here is a Gist listing all the commands required to make this happen: https://gist.github.com/neonexus/3062b34b09896fa027e22d332dd65069